# Regular expression help (getting invalid regular expression)

Tags: javascript, regex

I inherited a function written by another developer which I'm finding impossible to debug.

```
function getHighlightWordsForIssueHTML(cIssue, nIssueNum, arWordsToHighlight, strStartingHTML, strReplacementHTML)
{
var nIssueStartIndex = strStartingHTML.indexOf("<issuestart" + nIssueNum + "_");
var nIssueEndIndex = strStartingHTML.indexOf("<issueend" + nIssueNum + "_");
var strRelevantPart = strStartingHTML.slice(nIssueStartIndex, nIssueEndIndex);
for (var i = 0; i < arWordsToHighlight.length; i++)
{
    var strWord = arWordsToHighlight[i];
    strRelevantPart = strRelevantPart.replace(new RegExp(strWord, 'g'),
        String.format(strReplacementHTML, strWord));
}

strStartingHTML = strStartingHTML.replaceBetween(nIssueStartIndex,
        nIssueEndIndex, strRelevantPart);
return strStartingHTML;
}
```

This is returning an error for 
`strRelevantPart = strRelevantPart.replace(new RegExp(strWord, 'g'),`
when the text it is looking for (as caught by the strWord variable)  contains a parentheses. As in this example:

```
"12) months after the"
```

The error in question is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /12) months after the/: Unmatched ')'

Can you guys help me fix this?

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions to do a replacement when there's no expression? Just use the normal string replacement method.

Comment: In other words, just use `strRelevantPart.replace(strWord, String.format(strReplacementHTML, strWord));`

Comment: Ok. Just to be clear, I didn't write the function. I'm tasked (vexingly) with fixing it. I'm gonna try your fix, @Phylogenesis